# how to count the number of values that are greater than zero in OR-Tools

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat

I am using OR-Tools for an employees scheduling problem. I have a dictionary that is defined as an IntVar, where such dictionary contains the number of hours that will be assigned to each employee, ranging from zero to availability_for_day:

```
intvars[ID_VAR] = model.NewIntVar(0, availability_for_day, ID_VAR)
model.Add(sum[intvars[intv] for intv in intvars.keys()]<= availability_for_day
```

The ID_VAR keys for **intvars** are an f-string combination between dates *(yyyy-mm-dd)* and employee_id. I want to add a constraint that allows me to set a minimum number of employees that are assigned for a task for each day.
Therefore, my question is: how do I count how many intvars[intv] values are greater than zero? Then, how do I set the number of intvars[intv] that are greater than zero to be equal or greater than a minimum number of employees that I want to allocate?

So far, I have tried using another IntVar as a counter, but I could not make it work.

Answer (score 4):

You can a look at this [doc](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md).

You will create one Boolean variable per integer variable, and sum them.

Comment: I followed the documentation you linked, and created a Boolean variable for each employee, and such variable is "linked" to the Int variable value (it is true only if the int var is greater than zero). However, when I try doing this:
model.Add(sum(
                    [
                    boolvars[boolv] for boolv in boolvars.keys() 
                    ])
           )<= num_min_resources
I get this error: "NotImplementedError evaluating a LinearExpr instance as a Boolean is not implemented" 
Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: your code is wrong. One ')' is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

It's like bin packing problem. Just define set of binary variables $x_{d,s}$ where $d,s$ is same index as your intvar keys -(date d, staff s). Then add constraints
$ x_{d,s} \le H_{d,s} \le A_{d,s}x_{d,s} \\ \forall d,s $
where $H_{d,s} $ is your intvar and $A_{d,s}$ is available hours per $s$

$ L_d\le \sum_s x_{d,s} \ \forall d$
where $L$ is min staff required for date $d$

Comment: The API is different with CP-SAT. It uses indicator constraints instead of big-M.

Comment: @LaurentPerron I don't use CP-SAT, hoping the OP will get it. Most solvers will wave indicator constraints

Comment: yes, actually CP-SAT being SAT based use indicator constraints natively. bigM are recreated on the fly for the underlying (and optional) simplex.